# Script in php to create acrylic effect on image

Tags: php, image, effect

I want to create an acrylic or canvas effect on image when a user upload an image. How is it possible through an image library or through any other script or from command line with PHP?

For an example that how exact I am looking for you can follow these steps.

http://fineartamerica.com/create-art-online.html

1. open this link
2. upload a photo
3. select acrylic print from print options.

We just uploaded a simple image and this site convert this image into acrylic effect.
I want the same. I googled so much but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to write `any` code about it yet?

Comment: No didn't write any code. I have no idea how should i proceed.

Comment: Did you checked the link that what exact i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to imagemagick's convert utility you can do [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7688).

Also looking throught [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/) may give you some luck.